# How do I fix the The service "sanitize.userfields.commands" has a dependency on a non-existent service "entity.manager" error?

Tags: drush, 9

I am running Drush the first time in a Drupal 9 site. I get the following error.

> In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 86: The service "sanitize.userfields.commands" has a dependency on a non-existent service "entity.manager".

How can I fix this error?

`drush --version` and `drush cr` work.

Comment: At first glance looks like an outdated version of Drush, not compatible with Drupal v9. Try to upgrade

Comment: Currently, it is Drush Commandline Tool 10.0.3-dev

Comment: What command? A command provided by a module? Looks like it's not D9 ready. Can it be updated? It must have entity type manager instead. Can easily be fixed.

Comment: updated the question, drush was installed with drupal itself. Should we update it? How?

Comment: @hurdi and leymannx, upvoting you as it is solved by upgrading.

Comment: I had to upgrade drupal/webform to ^6.0.0.

Answer (score 10):

As folks (Hudri, leymannx) alluded to in the comments, `entity.manager` was deprecated in Drupal 8 which means it was **removed** in Drupal 9. The project that has the code that's calling `entity.manager` is not ready for Drupal 9 (or at least the version you have installed is not ready for Drupal 9). You may want to look for alternative modules if the one your using isn't ready for Drupal 9.

This one particular error is relatively simple to fix though, you may just need to replace any references to `entity.manager` with references to `entity_type.manager`. [This issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3075846) on d.o gives a good example of what you may have to do.

As @Jaypan noted in the comments, `entity_type.manager` may not always be the correct replacement. From the [*entity.manager* documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.2.x):

> Use \Drupal::entityTypeManager() [i.e. `entity_type.manager`] instead in most cases. If the needed method is not on \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface, see the deprecated \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager to find the correct interface or service.

Note: if this issue is being caused by a contributed package, e.g. a d.o module or theme or other package included by composer, you need to work within that project's issue queue to patch the project instead of updating the files directly in your codebase. At the very least, you'll want to create a local patch in your composer project and [configure composer to apply the patch](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches#usage).

Comment: thanks for explaining possible scenarios, upvoting you.

Comment: Note that `entity.manager` was split into multiple services, so `entity_type.manager` may not always be the correct replacement.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like Drush which came with the setup was not fully compatible.
I installed it again using the composer using

`composer require drush/drush`

It is working as expected.

Here is updated "require" section looks like in **composer.json**

```
   "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^4.28",
        "drupal/bootstrap_sass": "^1.12",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drush/drush": "^10.2"
    },
```

Comment: is working when i update to drush 10

Answer (score 0):

For me the below works, obviously nothing any better than a band-aid fix, but an immediate remedy to a blocker

- rm-rf vendor
- composer install

Answer (score 0):

Error I was facing  - The service "sanitize.userfields.commands" has a dependency on a non-existent service "entity.manager".

Drush old version 8

**Updating composer version resolved my issue.**

```
composer require drush/drush
```

After update Drupal version : 11.0.9
command to check drush version  `drush version`